# include std map inside pragma pack causes crash

Tags: c++, dictionary, include, pragma

I was wondering why inclusion of std map inside pragma pack (1) causes segmentation fault?
Does std map includes bit fields?

The seg fault occurs on the second insert to the map at "std::less::operator().. at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:387" and easy to reproduce:

```
#pragma pack (1)
#include <map>
#pragma pack
using namespace std;
... 
map<enum, pointerToClass>mapName

mapName.insert(pair<enum,pointerToClass>(enumValue, pointerToObject));
```

Comment: *and easy to reproduce:* -- Then it should be easy to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: For me it crashes inside `map::~map`, but `insert` works fine. (g++ 7.2.1)

Comment: The authors of `map` could have simply turned off your #pragma and use the correct settings within the `<map>` header file, overriding your `pragma pack(1)`.  So it makes no sense to try and pack what is not yours, even though you "successfully" got yourself into trouble by packing what isn't yours.

Comment: I agree. it was not my intention to pack external lib. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Standard library is not header only library. Some parts are compiled to `libstdc++.so.6`. So, there is *binary* code that expects some binary layout on standard library containers. For example `_Rb_tree_node::_Rb_tree_increment` is compiled.

By doing `pragma pack(1)`, you are changing binary layout of `_Rb_tree_node` what breaks iteration over `std::map` elements.

So, making `std::map` tightly packed would require `libstdc++` recompilation

Comment: The authors of `<map>` also could have put in a safety switch that would turn on the correct #pragma setting, overriding the OP's setting.  Probably this implementation didn't do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't advocate libstdc++ developers, but a library user could write `#define map banana` before `#include <map>`, right? Should they be prepared:-)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how you override it? by `#pragma pack(pop)`?